# Two different versions of Cohen's D? Which one to use?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, cohens-d

I am trying to measure the effect size of some variables between two different groups.

I've taken some python code from a few tutorials, but they seem to be calculating it in different ways.

I have two groups: `group_1` and `group_2`.

First method squares the standard deviations and divides by 2 (from datacamp.com):

```
pooled_standard_deviation = sqrt((group_1.std()**2 + group_2.std()**2)/2 )

cohens_d = difference_in_means / pooled_standard_deviation
```

Second method multiplies the sample size by the variance (machinelearningmastery.com):

```
# n1,n2 = sample sizes of groups 1 and 2

# s1,s2  = variances of groups 1 and 2

# u1,u2 = means of groups 1 and 2

pooled_standard_deviation  = sqrt(((n1 - 1) * s1 + (n2 - 1) * s2) / (n1 + n2 - 2))

cohens_d = (u1 - u2) / s
```

Which one is correct?

I'm guessing there's a very obvious reason for the difference but I just have no idea. (not a stats expert)

Comment: The first one assumes that the sample sizes are equal, it also does not make a correction for the fact that the variances are sample variances by not using the n-1 correction. The second is correct.

Comment: Thanks. My sample sizes are definitely not equal.